# $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_j b_{n-j} \to a^* \sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j$ if $a_n \to a^*$ and $\sum b_n$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive numbers which is converging to $a^*$ and a convergence series with running term $b_n$. Show that the convolution 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_j b_{n-j} \to a^* \sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j.$$

How can we use the dominated convergence theorem to prove this statement. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you need to use dominated convergence? If not, I think direct estimation of partial sums will be easier.

Comment: @mihaild It isn’t necessary but it was given as a hint. How can we directly estimate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false in general if the series $\sum b_n$ is not absolutely convergent. Take for example $a_j=2+(-1)^jj^{-1/2}$ and $b_j=(-1)^jj^{-1/2}$. Then $a_j$ tends to $a^*=2$ and $\sum_j b_j$ converges by the alternating series test, but it does not converge absolutely. If the statement were correct, we would also have $\lim_{n\to0}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_jb_{n-j}-2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}b_j\right)=0$ and therefore that $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(a_j-2)b_{n-j}$ tends to 0 as $n\to\infty$. By our choice of $a_j,b_{j}$, the latter sum is $S_n=(-1)^n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}1/\sqrt{j(n-j)}$. Since the function $x\mapsto x(n-x)$ has a minimum at $x=n/2$ which has the value $n^2/4$,
the absolute value is $|S_n|\geq (n-1)\frac2n$ and the latter expression tends to 2. Hence the sequence $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(a_j-2)b_{n-j}$, $n=2,3,...$, diverges in our example and we have reached a contradiction.
So the statement must be false in general.

Now, if the series $\sum b_n$ is absolutely convergent, the statement is correct. The sequence $a_n$ is bounded, say by $A$. We write 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_jb_{n-j}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}c_{n,j}b_{j}$$
where $c_{nj}=a_{n-j}$ if $j<n$ and $c_{nj}=0$ otherwise. Then $|c_{n,j}b_{j}|\leq A |b_j|$ for all $j$, the sum $\sum_j|b_j|$ converges and for each $j$,
the sequence $c_{nj}b_j$, $n=2,3,...$ tends to $a^*b_j$. The hypotheses of the dominated convergence theorem are satisfied, hence the limit exists and is $\sum_j a^*b_j$. Direct estimates instead of an application of dominated convergence are also possible, but they are a bit technical.

The statement is also true if $\sum_j(a_j-a^*)$ converges absolutely. The proof is analogous.